# How can I call another method after a method has executed without providing a callback?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

Within my application I have some inputs which call methods once their input text has changed. I create them using custom helpers, Ex:

```
@Helpers.GenerateProductFilter(string id, string value)
```

Which result in tags similar to this:

```
<input type="text" id="@id" value="@value" ng-model="SoftwareProductInput" ng-change="SoftwareProductChange()" />
```

As you can see, there is a method, `SoftwareProductChange()`, that gets called on change. My goal is to be able to add functionality to this method call when I need to.

So, for example, let's say that on one page I would like to have one of these inputs call their ng-change method and then immediately call another method that I can define for that page, let's call it `otherMethod()`.

Comment: You can modify your mvc helper to generate the `ng-change` to generate `SoftwareProductChange(); otherMethod();`

Comment: @xavvvier that was easier than I thought, thanks

Comment: I will add it as an answer then